# Laravel 7 Layout Problem (Navbar and Content)

Tags: laravel-blade, bootstrap-5, laravel-7

been struggling with my template using laravel 7 and bootstrap 5.2.3. my code was right based on my previous projects but this time I am having a problem in my layout.

in my app.blade.php, after the body tag, I put my codes like this.

```
 @extends('includes.navbar')
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4 container">
            @extends('includes.messages')
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
```

and navbar like this,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
    //links goes here
    </div>
</nav>
```

but the output is the content shown above and navbar below content. Please see photos below. can anyone help me, thanks ahead.

[image][image]

[image]

I already tried looking for solutions over the internet but I didn't see anything related to my concern.

Comment: I think there's somethings wrong with the package installation, template and file extension.
can you provide composer.json, the whole file, and its name ( extension )
In my experience, you should create entirely new demo project with the same laravel-7. if it works, compare it with the current project to find out the cause.
Usually, this's caused by very small, little, petty issues.

Comment: @nhy, here is the composer.json

Comment: {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "2.4",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0"
    }

Comment: So sorry for the slow response, I did create a repo to reproduce the issue. i think you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/nguyenhy/SO-reproduce-laravel-7-blade).
I first create a repo using laravel 7, then add /includes folder and use your template in the first code block you provide.

Comment: Oops. After reading your issue description I realized that I misunderstood the problem you're facing. I thought you can't use `blade` template inside for `view.blade.php`. My bad.
Can you describe in more detail what you're facing and what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think you should read document of [@extends](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#extending-a-layout) and [@include](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews)

TLDR:

- `@extends`: to extend a layout

  - `app.blade.php` is a layout
- `@include`: to include subviews

  - `includes.navbar`: is a subview
  - `includes.messages`: is a subview
- before

```php
 @extends('includes.navbar')
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4 container">
            @extends('includes.messages')
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
```

- after

```
@include('includes.navbar') {{-- use include instead of extends --}}
<div id="app">
    <main class="py-4 container">
        @include('includes.messages') {{-- use include instead of extends --}}
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>
```

I suggest:

- create a `/layouts` folder inside `<root>/views/`
- create a app.blade.php

  ```php
  @include('includes.navbar')
  <div id="app">
      <main class="py-4 container">
          @include('includes.messages')
          @yield('content')
      </main>
  </div>
  ```
- use layout

  ```
  // some controller
  Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
  });
  ```

  ```
  // <root>/views/welcome.blade.php
  @extends('layouts.layout')
  @section('content')
  this is content of "yield('content')"
  @endsection
  ```
- Update

1. I create [repo](https://github.com/nguyenhy/SO-reproduce-laravel-7-blade) to reproduce this problem. and you can checkout the commit as a step by step produce/resolve it

Comment: Hi. I forgot the usage of theses two. thanks for reminding me. this solved my problem.  thank you so much sir!! and also to all who responses here, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

did you check for your CSS styles for the navbar and the content you didn't provide any CSS code so its not easy to determine the problem
try to make the navbar higher in the Z index and make it at the top of the page
You can also try adjusting the padding and margin values to ensure that the content is properly aligned.

if this doesn't work you can try to use the grid system of bootstrap or the new version that uses the flex to create a container for the navbar and the content to help ensure that they are properly aligned and positioned.
I hope this helps!